# ajax can't display hash sign

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have this code of HTML

```
<textarea cols="120" rows="4" name="editor" id="editor" onkeyup="sendData()"></textarea>
<span id="container" name="container"></span>
```

and this one in JS

```
function sendData(){
var hc = document.getElementById('editor').value;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "w.php?h=" + hc, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

also this one in w.php

```
<?php
$h = $_REQUEST['h'];
echo $h;
?>
```

when i use this code it's work very fine but there is a problem with tow letters first one "#" and second one "&" so how can i fix this problem :)
thank you

Comment: `html_entity_decode()`

Comment: @AwladLiton thank you i just used encodeURLComponent and it work very well thank you again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to encode your data for a URI. Simply use

```
encodeURIComponent(/* The data to encode here. */)
```

before creating your request URL.

Comment: i try it but in different place so it did not work with me so i asked my question here but now i try it after defining hc so it's work lol thank you